# Set size of Matlab eps figure

Tags: matlab, printing, matlab-figure, eps

I am using the following code in Matlab

```
figure
mesh(AAA,BBB,ZZZ)
set(gcf,'Position', [560 528 560*2 420*(1/2)])
colorbar
print -depsc2 -painters XXX.eps
```

However, the following line:

```
set(gcf,'Position', [560 528 560*2 420*(1/2)])
```

does not seem to have any influence on the output file. Thus, how can I specify the dimensions of the output file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the [`'Paperposition'`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html?refresh=true#prop_PaperPosition) property of the figure (not `'Position'`):

```
set(gcf,'Paperposition',[left bottom width height]);
```

The numbers `left`, `bottom` etc are in units determined by the [`'PaperUnits'`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html?refresh=true#prop_PaperUnits) property, which can also be modified.

Comment: To which Matlab version does this apply? I can't seem to find any details. Maybe that is an indication that it applies to all....?

Comment: @kkuilla I think I remember very old Matlab versions that already had that property, but I'm not sure